# Assets and/or angular issue? "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]" Using: Heroku, Rails 4, Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am getting pretty desperate. I am using Angular, Rails 4 and deploying with Heroku. The web-app runs fine locally; however, there are some issues after I deploy.

[Along with a blank screen, these are the errors in the browser console on page load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBG9C.png)

All the scripts on my public/index.html file are unable to be found. Heroku logs yields "no route matches" for each of the scripts that load js, html, and css info. At the same time, I cannot solve the "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]" error.

I have tried:

- precompiling assets
- changing settings in my environment/production.rb file
- fixing injection dependency issues with angular

  [configure/environment/production.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9W7.png)

My hunch is that it all is an assets issue - and my index.html file is unable to connect with my module, which throws more errors. Do I have to put all js, css, and html files in the assets folder after precompiling? How do I use assets effectively?

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!